# SQLSTATE[42000] Syntax error or access violation Row size too large

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting the following error while running my joomla xmlImport.php file.

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too
large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row
format, BL
```

OB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.

As many of them suggested I have increased `innodb_log_file_size` to 128M but still I am getting the same error. Can sombody help me on this?

Comment: How big is a typical record from your imported data?  Did you try taking the advice from the error output and using `TEXT` or `BLOB`?

Answer (score 4):

innodb_log_file_size setting does not affect this error. The error is about a row exceeding mysql's max row length limitation. You need to review the create table statement and either

- reduce certain column lengths
- change some varchar columns' data type to text or blob
- change the row format as suggested in the error message
- change character encoding to sg that fits your requirements, but uses less bytes.

Comment: Thanks that was my case... especially my table has a lot of columns i grouped under json type taking necessary columns