# Trigger not working with longtext field

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have 2 MySQL table name *uploads* and *uploads_log*.

- *uploads* table has a field name *json_values* (datatype: longtext)
- *uploads_log* table has 2 fields *old_value*, *new_value* (both datatype: longtext)

On After UPDATE of *uploads* table I have written a trigger which just put the whole content of *uploads.json_values* into *uploads_log* table's old_value, new_value.

trigger is

```
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.json_values != OLD.json_values) THEN
        INSERT INTO uploads_log (`file_id`, `user_id`, `field_name`, `old_value`, `new_value`, `ip`, `created_at`)
        VALUES (OLD.`file_id`,
                OLD.`user_id`,
                'json_values',
                OLD.json_values,
                NEW.json_values,
                NEW.user_ip,
                NOW());
    END IF;
END
```

**My issue is:** When I'm editing small string in `uploads.json_values` my trigger is working fine, but when Im editting some realy long string like **378369 characters long**. I'm getting the following error.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.

I try to debug the issue I removed the trigger and EDITED `uploads.json_values` with long string it workes fine, and I manually INSERTED that long string into `uploads_log.old_value` then also it works fine, So the issue is with the trigger.

Is trigger has some limitataion of length?

Both the table uses Storage Engine: InnoDB and MySQL Version is 5.6.21.

> `uploads` table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `uploads` (
 `file_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `json_values` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `read_values` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `user_ip` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`file_id`),
 KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34444 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

> `uploads_log` table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `uploads_log` (
 `action_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `file_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `field_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `old_value` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `new_value` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `ip` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`action_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22637733/5019802) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34804962/5019802), but it is not related to UPDATE trigger.

Any help/suggestion will be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: please add output of show create table

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25578580/1541403)

Comment: @e4c5: I have updated my question with table structure. and Vatev I'm also reading this answer but having an hard time to digest it. so googling it.

Comment: What table is the trigger on?

Comment: @e4c5: Trigger is written in `uploads` table, and it is getting fired after table update.

Comment: and you did try changing the row format to compressed as suggested in the error message right?

Comment: phpMyAdmin **does not** has any option to change `ROW_FORMAT` to `compressed`, So I cannot able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had some similar issue but not with trigger this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/1261) helped me out.

Change `innodb_log_file_size` value located in `C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini` (*if you are using XAMPP*) to something higher than 5M.

or as pointed out by @Vatev you can set `innodb_log_file_size = 128M`

You can use this MySQL command to get the `innodb_log_file_size` value, it will give you the result in Byte.

Comment: thanks, it did work for me on local/dev server, but is there any other way to achieve this, because I don't know I'll have any option to change MySQL configuration on shared hosting.